# No keyboard input in Qt Creator after update to Qt5

Tags: qt-creator, qt5

I have this strange situation that after updating Qt from 4.8 to 5.3, Qt Creator (v.3.2.1) will not take any keyboard input. The keyboard is working normally in other applications.

I'm on Debian Wheezy (7.7) with XFCE, but installed the Qt5 set of packages from wheezy-backports. 
Does anyone have an idea what can be done about this?

**Update:**
As requested, here's the Terminal output:

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
xkbcommon:ERROR: failed to add default include path auto
Qt: Failed to create XKB context!
Use QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT environmental variable to provide an addtional search path, 
add ':' as separator to provide several search paths and/or make sure that XKB 
configurationdata directory contains recent enough contents, to update please see 
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/ .
```

Comment: Can you open a console, type `qtcreator` and update your question with the messages you obtain?

Comment: @prajmus No, shortcuts don't work either.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is apparently a known bug, some messages and posts talks about this issue on the Internet.

Maybe try this, from https://lists.debian.org/debian-backports/2014/10/msg00061.html

> Opening Qt5 applications from backports (or self compiled against backported 
>   Qt5) have some trouble finding XCB data:
>
> $ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples/quick/d
>   ialogs/systemdialogs/systemdialogs
>   xkbcommon: ERROR: failed to add default include path auto
>   Qt: Failed to create XKB context!
>   Use QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT environmental variable to provide an additional search 
>   path, add ':' as separator to provide several search paths and/or make sure 
>   that XKB configuration data directory contains recent enough contents, to 
>   update please see http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/ .
>
> Applications run fine, but can't get input from the keyboard.
>
> As the warning points out, setting the environment variable fixes it:
>
> export QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT=/usr/share/X11/xkb

So, try to run qtcreator with the folowing command:

```
export QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT=/usr/share/X11/xkb && qtcreator
```

Comment: I had to do the export and qtcreator start in two steps, but now it's working again. Thanks a lot to everyone!

Comment: If you are logging in from a SSH client and get the error message requesting the QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT variable. Then go to your home directory of the user you are logging in and insert the line export QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT=/usr/share/X11/xkb at the end of the file .bashrc

Comment: The reason @virt had to separate the commands is probably due to the race condition resulting from the start of the first command in background (`&`). Use `&&` to separate the two commands, to start them in sequence.

Comment: Recently I upgraded my pyqt and this error accrued for me and I want to say to those who have same problem in spyder that this solution is worked for me too!!Thanks

Comment: I am getting this error while using cv2.imshow(), any workaround?

Comment: QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT=/usr/share/X11/xkb at the end of the file .bashrc worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

~]$ /usr/local/bin/xca

xkbcommon: ERROR: failed to add default include path /usr/share/X11/xkb
Qt: Failed to create XKB context!
Use QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT environmental variable to provide an additional search path, add ':' as separator to provide several search paths and/or make sure that XKB configuration data directory contains recent enough contents, to update please see http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/ .

sudo apt-get install xkb-data (xkeyboard-config)

has solved my problem (no input from keyboard)

Comment: Please add an explaination, how this willl solve the issue in the question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Adding `apt-get install xkb-data` to my docker file solved the problem of having no keyboard inputs with a Dockerized Qt application.

Comment: On CentOS this is `yum install -y xkeyboard-config`.  

My use case: I'm creating a Docker container for development purposes to run on my local machine a PyQt app that is usually run in a RHEL environment.